# Execute action after an element is clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

For school we need to make a memory game. We're at the point that we have the cards and you can sort them. But now we need to check if 2 elements are clicked, and then execute an action. All the div's have an unique Id and a same class. I know you can do it for one element with .click, but I was wondering whether you can do something like that for 2 elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could make a boolean `isClicked` and set it to true when one element is clicked. And then in the onclick `if (isClicked)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, every time a card is clicked, you indicate that it *has* been clicked, and then count the number of cards that have that indicator, you can determine whether or not to run the additional logic. Assuming your cards each have a class "card" to indicate that the elements are cards, the code would look something like this:

```
$('.card').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('clicked'); // indicate that this card has been clicked
    // any other logic run every time a card is clicked, such as turning it face up
    if($('.card.clicked').length === 2) { // query all .card.clicked elements, and compare the length (number of matched elements) to 2
        // run logic if two cards have been clicked
        $('.card.clicked').removeClass('clicked'); // clear the "clicked" indicators
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind click event using same class and count click event and store in a variable.

Try this

```
var clickCount=0;
$('.class-name') .click(function(){
  clickCount++;
  if(clickCount==2){
     // Execute your action here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;

function clickatag(){
  if(clicked) return;
  clicked = true;

  // all of your code //

  clicked = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p ondblclick="myFunction()">Double-click this paragraph to trigger a function.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use ondblclick event